# How do I set the next roll/colour on the click of a button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I currently have a roulette gamemode which is mostly coded in javascript and uses node.js on a linux server (debian 7) to start the site etc. I am trying to implement a 'set roll' page where I can set the number of the next roll. The number order is; [1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4, 0, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8]. When the roulette rolls currently, it is fast and it lands on a nrandom number as it isn't yet rigged. I tried changing `dist += 1050 * 5;`on both of the function to `dist == (I PUT NUMBER HERE);` but then when the roulette rolls, it only rolls literally a tiny bit and doesn't land on the number I put. Anyone have any ideas?

```
function snapRender(x, wobble) {
    CASEW = $("#case").width();
    if (isMoving) return;
    else if (typeof x === 'undefined') view(snapX);
    else {
        var order = [1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4, 0, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8];
        var index = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
            if (x == order[i]) {
                index = i;
                break
            }
        }
        var max = 32;
        var min = -32;
        var w = Math.floor(wobble * (max - min + 1) + min);
        var dist = index * 70 + 36 + w;
        dist += 1050 * 5;
        snapX = dist;
        view(snapX)
    }
}

function spin(m) {
    var x = m.roll;
    play_sound("roll");
    var order = [1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4, 0, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8];
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        if (x == order[i]) {
            index = i;
            break
        }
    }
    var max = 32;
    var min = -32;
    var w = Math.floor(m.wobble * (max - min + 1) + min);
    var dist = index * 70 + 36 + w;
    dist += 1050 * 5;
    animStart = new Date().getTime();
    vi = getVi(dist);
    tf = getTf(vi);
    isMoving = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        finishRoll(m, tf)
    }, tf);
    render()
}
```